# The Chronology Challenge: earliest verifiable date of a historical event?

Tags: chronology, date, timeline

If we go backwards in time using verifiable dates, what is the earliest event which can be associated with a specific day without question?

I am most interested in answers that actually show the chain of dates, not just an empty assertion (professor so and so said May 5, 2050 BC, is the earliest date...). For example, we know that the [Inter gravissimas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter_gravissimas) was issued on February 24, 1582, (old style) and that thereby October 4, 1582, was to be followed by October 15, 1582.

Therefore, given that in the Cronica Majora by Matthew of Paris it says that Harold Godwinson crowned himself king of England on the day that Edward was buried, which was "die Epiphaniae" (the day of the Epiphany, January 6th) in MLXVI Anno Domini. Since this was a date by the Roman calendar we can presume by the Gregorian calendar the event occurred exactly on the day 16 January 1066, 10 days later, assuming the Roman calendar used by Matthew was fully intact and continuous to 1582. Now, if you read any history book, such as the one cited by the Wikipedia, DeVries, K. (1999). "The Norwegian Invasion of England in 1066." (Woodbridge, UK: Boydell Press), it will say Harold became king on Jan 6, 1066, but we have just proved this is not true.

By this exercise we have shown that the dates you find in history books are often wrong. So, this brings us to the question again, going backwards from verifiable evidence what is the earliest event we can positively assign to a particular day. I have shown that we can assign the ascension of Harold to 16 January 1066, but I assume it is possible to go backwards much farther. The question is how much farther?

**What is Meant by a Verifiable Date**

By a verifiable date, I mean one where we can show absolutely the passage in time by days to the present day. For example, if the ascension of Harold occurred on January 16, 1066, and today is August 21, 2014, then we might think that the ascension of Harold took place 346461 days ago, or 948 years, 7 months, and 5 days ago. But is this really true? For example, if we consider that in 1066 the New Year occurred on April 1, not January 1st, then it is possible he ascended 949 years ago, not 948 years ago. An interesting question.

Aside from any calendar, how far back can we name the number of days to a particular event in history with confidence? Now, the person most expert at doing this was Joseph Scaliger, who invented the concept of the Julian Day for this exact purpose, and I am familar a little bit with some of the things he wrote, but since theoretically we have progressed in the last 200 years since Scaliger, I am thinking maybe someone has improved on his work. Hence the question.

Comment: You have miscalculated the Calendar correction in winter 1065-66; it should be only 6 days as the accumulated error of 10 days in 1582 includes errors (by the Gregorian Calendar) from the years 1100, 1300, 1400, and 1500.  Thus Harold Godwinson crowned himself on December 31, 1065 Anno Domini (Gregorian). (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar)

Comment: It is universal practice of students of ancient and mediaeval history to use the Julian calendar to date events before the introduction of the Gregorian reform. The dates in history books are not “wrong”. All calendars are equally correct as long as you know which calendar you are using.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens We are not trying to synchronize to the seasons here. My demonstration is conversion to a Gregorian date, since I am assuming Gregorian dates are 10 days later than Roman dates then January 6 OS must be January 16th Gregorian.

Comment: @fdb My experience is that historians simply record whatever date they read regardless of the calendar. For example, you can find many old dates for Eastern European events which use the Byzantine calendar and no conversion to the Roman calendar has been done, so saying it was a "universal" practice to use the "Julian calendar" does not seem correct to me.

Comment: I do not have the impression that you understand the difference between a calendar and an era. The Byzantine calendar IS the Julian calendar. But the Julian calendar can be used in conjunction with different eras (AD era, Seleucid era, Byzantine world era ...)

Comment: FDB seems to have the idea that "converting" an ancient date is easy. The point of the question is to ascertain if that is true. From what I know of ancient it is actually very difficult to precisely date an event before about 1000 A.D. That's why I asking for a chain of events that proves such a calculation.

Comment: I am afraid you are talking total rubbish.

Comment: @fdb Well, so far I have demonstrated a proof of a date going back 1000 years, a simple proof no doubt, but at least a demonstration of something. You have demonstrated nothing, so who is talking rubbish? If you are so knowledgeable then demonstrate a verifiable date older than 1066.

Comment: There are lots of very good books about calendars. You could start with “Calendars in Antiquity : Empires, States, and Societies” by Sacha Stern, 2012.

Comment: As for me not having demonstrated anything, you might want to look at this: http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/crai_0065-0536_2006_num_150_2_87108

Comment: @fdb I could not see how to download that document. Does it have a verifiable date in it earlier than 1066?

Comment: If you are interested in calendars go to http://www.raymondm.co.uk/ and request the "kairos" demo.

Comment: Obviously I asked too hard a question. I will delete it tomorrow, if no meaningful answer appears. Sorry for presenting you with too difficult a question. Next one will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 10):

I know this would not be to OP's liking (considering his expressed opinion of Chinese history), but other people might find this interesting.

The earliest event in Chinese history with a **verifiable *year*** is the [**Interregnum**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonghe_%28regency%29) following the expulsion of [King Li from the Zhou Kingdom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Li_of_Zhou). With the king exiled, his chief ministers ruled the realm in his stead. They declared the year, 841 B.C. , to be the **[first year (*epoch*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) of the *Joint Harmony* era.**

That event's significance is that it marked the **beginning of *consistent and preserved* record keeping** in China. The epoch changes with whenever the person on the throne changes - the Joint Harmony era terminated after 14 years, with the coronation of [King Xuan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Xuan_of_Zhou) becoming the new epoch. However, records were kept and added to year after year by every subseqeunt Chinese governement. Major events and government affairs were hence forth recorded by *contemporary* court historians in official [**annals**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annals) - as opposed to being written down by a later historian.

Most of the early records have, unfortunately, been lost over time. The earliest annal in *continuous* survival is that of the [State of Lu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lu_%28state%29). Here is the year 722-721 B.C., from the State of Lu's official annals with rough translations:

```
隱公元年
    春，王正月。                         //Spring, January
    三月，公及邾儀父盟于蔑。              //March, pact made with the Baron of Zou
    夏，五月，鄭伯克段于鄢。              //Summer, May, Count of Zheng defeated his brother.
    秋，七月，天王使宰咺來歸惠公仲子之賵。 //Autumn, July, emissary from the King
    九月，及宋人盟于宿。                 //September, pact made with the Duke of Song
    冬，十有二月，祭伯來。               //Winter, December, the Count of Zhai visited.
      公子益師卒。                      //Lord Yi passed away.

二年
    春，公會戎于潛。              //Spring, met with barbarians.
    夏，五月，莒人入向。          //Summer, May, Ju's lord visited
      無駭帥師入極。              //General Zhan attacked Ji.
    秋，八月，庚辰，公及戎盟于唐。 //Autumn, August, day of gēngchén, pact with barbarians
    九月，紀裂繻來逆女。          //September, bridal escort arrived from Ji
    冬，十月，伯姬歸于紀。        //Winter, October, princess leaves for Ji
      紀子帛莒子，盟于密。       //Barons of Zi and Ju allied
    十有二月，乙卯，夫人子氏薨。  //December, day of yǐmǎo, the Duchess passed away.
      鄭人伐衛。                 //Zheng attacked Wey
```

Of special interest are the August and December entries (Lu's pact with the barbarians, and the death of Lu's duchess), which specified the dates. As far as I know, *these are the earliest events in Chinese history that have **verifiable exact dates**.*

Note that these records are made in the traditional Chinese calendar, but that can be of course be converted to Gregorian dates.

Comment: The problem of course is manuscripts written long after the supposed events. The wiki claims that there exists a 5th century mss of the Records of the Grand Historians without citing. Just even knowing what this mss is, I guess I would find pretty interesting, since all the Chinese originals I know of are much later than that.

Comment: Also, let's for the sake of argument suppose we have a 5th century mss and it gives a 722 BC date. Are you claiming that the calendar used was never altered and was continuous to the 5th century, and to the present time? This seems kind of unbelievable to me. I had thought the Chinese used regnal years, which would make it impossible to locate a date straight off the bat because of uncertainty when a particular ruler died or came to the throne. Even in Europe regnal years cannot be used for precise dates without additional corroboration.

Comment: @TylerDurden Is your complaint that the original records on bamboo has been lost, and all we have available now is copies?

Comment: The Chinese calendar names each year using a combination of specific characters that repeats every 60 years. Regnal years, and later era names, are imposed upon this system. The combination identifies the precise year in question, because given that records are *continuous* on a yearly basis, it is exceedingly unlikely to misidentify a reigning emperor by an error of 60 years.

Comment: This is why 841 B.C. is identified as the start of Chinese historical records, because prior to that dates are not kept consistently enough for identification. That's why there is a range of decades on the year given for King Wu's foundation of the Zhou dynasty.

Comment: "Is your complaint that the original records on bamboo has been lost, and all we have available now is copies?" Not only that, its that the so-called "copies" are full of anachronisms and written in modern Chinese and we have no corroborating evidence, like contemporaneous stone monuments for example. Its like imagine we had a "copy" of De Bello Gallico written in English with Caesar looking at his watch to find out what time it is and the author claiming it was written in 40 B.C.

Comment: @TylerDurden do you have **any** source whatsoever for the claim that they are "full of anachronisms and written in modern Chinese"? Because if you tell that to a billion Chinese, a billion of them will laugh at you while they remember their high school Classical Chinese lessons.

Comment: Heck, just this passage cited in my answer is emphatically **not** modern Chinese.

Comment: Comments are not really the right forum to argue about the historicity of Chinese annals. As for Chinese students laughing at me, are these the same students who come to the United States and copy each others work and represent it to their professors as their own work? There do seem to be a billion of those. Getting back to the Records of the Grand Historian. Would you know if there is a photograph of this supposed 5th century manuscript anywhere?

Comment: @TylerDurden Still waiting for your ludicrous claim to be backed up by something other than "the completely baseless opinion of @TylerDurden". You can ask about Shiji in another question.

Comment: Since you did not respond to my request for more information about the 5th century mss, I am I to assume you know of no evidence of such an mss? As far as the historicity question is concerned, I think even if I spent the hours necessary to write a long essay on the subject, you would simply pooh-pooh it and make up your own explanations. Your confidence in such sources is more a religious belief than a scientific logic and it is impossible to reason with zealots.

Comment: @TylerDurden Nice try at baiting, but I'm still not biting. Again, if you want to ask about Shiji make it its own question: it is completely irrelevant to my answer no matter how much you clearly wants to change topics to avoid admitting being hopelessly wrong. The fact is once again, you prove incapable of providing **a single shred of evidence** to support your ridiculously unscientific and outlandish claims that are painfully obviously rooted in ignorance. Dress up your self-righteous arrogance all you like, you are still only making unsubstantiated claims with no evidence whatsoever.

Answer (score 7):

There are lots of documents in Sumerian and Akkadian with precise dates mentioned in the documents themselves. These go back well into the 3rd millennium BC. These can be converted without difficulty into Julian or Gregorian dates.

But of course, all this depends on what you mean by “events”. If you include astronomical events visible on earth (eclipses, novae etc) then these can be dated down to a fraction of a second by astronomical science; this will take you back millions of years.

Comment: Ok, if it is so easy, demonstrate it. My question asks for historical events, not astronomical ones. If you want to try to prove a date using an astronomical event, that is fine with me, so long as the date being proved is a historical day on which something historical happened.

Comment: An eclipse is "something historical".

Comment: By historical I mean a human event, things men and women have done.

Comment: Enjoy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_of_Thales

Comment: @congusbongus Well, you certainly have given the best answer so far to my question. I do know about this eclipse. The problem is that there is a lot of ambiguity of whether Herodotus' eclipse is the same one as the NASA suggested eclipse. If you read the wiki article you can see they recognize this. If you look at eclipse charts you can see that there is uncertainty. I actually have a reference book on EVERY historically referenced eclipse. The trick though is that they all have a certain amount of ambiguity unless combined other info, which is where it gets complex.

Comment: Let me add that there are many Babylonian tablets recording astronomical observations on specified dates. These can be checked with modern methods. Ptolemy’s Almagest (2nd century AD) records many of his own observations with the day and month of the Egyptian calendar and the year according to the era of Nabonidus. These too can easily be verified. All of this is long before the year 1000.

Comment: @fdb The almagest is a good source and can probably be used to get specific dates back to at least the time of Caesar with some work. Babylonian observations that I know of are more ambiguous (a bunch of eclipses of uncertain date). In any case the question asks for an example or demonstration or a result showing how far back we can go reliably, not merely the assertion it can be done (I know it can be done).

Comment: Ok, one example: Almagest xi, 7, where Ptolemy cites an observation on the 5th of the Macedonian month Xanthikos of the year 82 “according to the Chaldaeans” (i.e., the Babylonian lunar calendar with Seleucid years), equating this with the 14th of the Egyptian month Tybi 519 of Nabonassar. Both of these dates correspond to 1 March -228 (227 BC) Julian.